# I got error in node.js as cannot find name ' Userdetailshistory' array, so why it is coming I didn't recognized properly in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserdetailshistoryService } from '../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-userdetailshistory',
  templateUrl: './userdetails-history.component.html',
})

export class UserdetailshistoryComponent implements OnInit{

userdetailshistorys: Userdetailshistory[];

constructor(private userdetailshistoryService: UserdetailshistoryService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.userdetailshistoryService.getUserdetailsHistory().then(userdetailshistorys => this.userdetailshistorys = userdetailshistorys);
}

}
```

Comment: You you please edit your question and make your code look like code. Helps the readability! :)

Comment: So `Userdetailshistory`-class isn't recognized? You haven't imported it to your component.

Comment: yaaa you telling right right now its working.

Comment: Great, will you accept my answer below, so people don't need to look at this, since it's solved! :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to import `Userdetailshistory` to your `UserdetailshistoryComponent`.